# How to have query in rewritten URL

Tags: php, .htaccess

Basically, I would like to know how to add a query parameter at the end of the rewritten URL.

Example:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1
```

`example.com?page=test` will become `example.com/test`

But now I want to know if it's possible to have something like this:

`example.com/test/?nexturl=somenexturl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use `QSA` flag in your rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Or even shorter:

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

`QSA` (Query String Append) flag preserves existing query parameters while adding a new one.

Comment: This is amazing. Thank you.